# When profiling, what's a correct (or good) way to accumulate callee times to callers?

Tags: lua, profile

When you're profiling code with recursive functions, deciding how to accumulate time spent in callees up to their callers becomes tricky.  If you profile the following code (Lua):

```
function a(n)
  wait(10)
  if n > 0 then
    a(n-1)
  end
end

a(1)
```

and, for the purposes of the analysis, only the line `wait(10)` takes any time, what child time should be attributed to the line `a(n-1)`?

Two nice properties of a profile would be that:

1. The child time for a function should be the sum of the child times of its lines (and likewise for self time)
2. The sum of the child and self times for a line would be what you would measure if you wrapped the line in calls to `os.clock()` (or equivalent)

If `a(n-1)` gets a child time of 0, then you get (1), but not (2).  If `a(n-1)` gets a child time of 10, you get (2), but not (1).

I've read, but possibly not understood, [this paper about gprof](http://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/psd/18.gprof/paper.pdf).  As far as I can tell, they agree it's a tricky problem and their solution would give `a(n-1)` a child time of 0.  I'm not sure how it would work in a case of `a()` calling `b()` calling `a()`.

Does anyone have any insight into whether 0 or 10 is a better answer and why?  Or, even better, have another solution that respects both (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This paper about gprof](http://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/psd/18.gprof/paper.pdf) by Graham, Kessler and McCusick describes

- gprof in general
- cycle detection and a method of time propagation in the case of cycles

Comment: Thanks, that's the paper I meant by "gprof docs". I probably should have been clearer and said, like you, "this paper about gprof".  As I (mis?)understand it, the paper says that they don't propagate times in a cycle at all, which I think would give uninformative results when a() calls b() and then b() calls a() (and so on).

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice you linked to the paper too. In case of cycles, there is no correct solution on my opinion and you will have to make choices. Do what helps you most. Perhaps you have a concrete profiling case to solve? Sorry again, I cannot offer you more.

Comment: Right, thanks - it's very helpful to know you don't think there's a correct solution.  If, as you say, I can choose, then I'm leaning towards the second option above - in the hope that it's simpler. My attempt at implementing the first is horribly complicated and still wrong.